# C++,deallocating already deallocated does not give a compiler error

Tags: c++, class, pointers, memory-management

Firstly I have three file,

*mystring.cpp* which is for implementation of functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mystring.hpp"

// Default constructor
MyString::MyString()
{
    data = 0;
    length = 0;
}

MyString::MyString(int n)
{
    data = new char [n];
    length = n;
}

MyString::MyString(const char* str, int n)
{
    length = n;
    data = new char [n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        data[i] = str[i];
    }
}

void MyString::trim(int n)
{
    if(n < length)
    {
        int newlength = n;
        char* newdata = new char [newlength];

        for (int i = 0; i < newlength; i++)
        {
        newdata[i] = data[i];
        }

        delete[] data;

        data = newdata;
        length = newlength;
    }
}

MyString::~MyString()
{
  delete[] data;
}




void MyString::append(const MyString& rhs)
{
    // Determine the length of the resulting
    // string and allocate room for it.
    int newlength = length + rhs.length;
    char* newdata = new char [newlength];

    // Copy the current string's data
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        newdata[i] = data[i];
    }

    // Copy the given string's data
    for (int i = 0; i < rhs.length; i++)
    {
        newdata[i + length] = rhs.data[i];
    }

    // Now we must deallocate the original memory
    // and update the member variables
    delete[] data;

    data = newdata;
    length = newlength;
}



void MyString::print(char separator) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
    {

        std::cout << data[i] << separator;
    }

    std::cout << data[length - 1] << std::endl;
}
```

secondly a header file which is *mystring.hpp*

```
        #ifndef __mystring_hpp__
    #define __mystring_hpp__

class MyString
{
    public:
        // Constructors
        MyString();
        MyString(int n);
        MyString(const char* str, int n);
         ~MyString(); 

        // Modify the current string by appending "rhs" to it
        void append(const MyString& rhs);

        // Trim the string such that it contains "n" characters.
        // If "n" is larger than the current string's length,
        // then do nothing.
        void trim(int n);

        // Prints this string by putting the separator
        // character between each element in the data.
        // By default, do not print anything.
        void print(char separator = '\0') const;

        // This is the destructor. It is automatically
        // called when an object of this class is destroyed.
        //~MyString(); //Implement!

        // This is the assignment operator which is automatically
        // called when an object of type MyString is assigned
        // to another object of the same type. Technically, it
        // does not have to return "MyString&" but we do so to
        // allow chaining assignments such as: str1 = str2 = str3
        //MyString& operator=(const MyString& rhs); //Implement!

        // Copy constructor. Different from the assignment operator,
        // this is called when an object is "being created" as a
        // copy of another object.
        //MyString(const MyString& rhs); //Implement!

    private:
        char* data;
        int length;
};

    #endif // __mystring_v1_hpp__
```

And finally main_assignment.cpp which includes main.cpp

```
#include "mystring.hpp"

int main()
{
    MyString str1("ali", 3);
    MyString str2("veli", 4);

    str1 = str2;


    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that , I did not overloaded assignment operator for MyString class , so in *main_assignment.cpp  *    the two strings should point the same memory and when the program returns , it should try to deallocate the  one of two first but when it comes to the other one it will try to deallocate a pointer which poinst some "undefined " memory .

From my point of view , it should crash but program works flawless , why ?

Comment: Because it is named _undefined_ behavior for a reason.

Comment: `__mystring_hpp__` -- Do not use leading double underscores as an identifier.  Identifier with leading double underscores are reserved for the compiler implementation.

Comment: Off topic, but some advice -- your `trim` function should only need to change the `length`.  There really isn't any need to reallocate and copy the same data over again -- let the `length` control the number of characters the string actually has.

Comment: @user9679818: which OS, which compiler, which build mode and which platform are you compiling for? I copy/pasted your code, compiled in VS2017 and it crashes in both debug and release build x86.

Comment: @trim thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior of a program when you `delete` a pointer twice is [*undefined*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). That means the standard does not specify what should happen in this case - in particular it does not specify that the program should crash. It might - or it might behave as expected - or it might continue but behave in unexpected ways that seem to have no relation whatever to the part of the code where the undefined behavior was invoked.

Answer (score -2):

As already mentioned by @TypeIA, the behavior of a double free is *undefined* in the C++ specification.

And, in fact, it [has been implemented](https://feross.org/gcc-ownage/) as an easter egg in GCC 1.17. However, note that this was done for "specific cases" only. The compiler would need to be very very sure that undefined behavior is invoked before it launches some games.

In most cases, the compiler cannot be that sure to start the easter egg. E.g. double frees are typically not implemented in one method like in your simplified case. They happen e.g. after reading a faulty file from disk, or if the user presses buttons in the wrong order etc. That's information which is simply not available at compile time.

So, any normal compiler will likely compile something that corresponds to what you wrote in your code. (However, the optimizer might get into your way and delete unused variables etc. This sometimes needs to be considered when writing demo code.)

If that were not the case, you would need to live with the fear that any bug in your program sends an email to your employer quitting your job, publishes all your photos on Reddit and then formats your hard drive.

Ok, that's my opinion about undefined behavior. Not very popular maybe, and I may deserve some downvotes for saying above things. However, [I have debugged a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windbg/topusers) and from my 10 years of experience in WinDbg, I would say things are generally quite predictable and debuggable.

---

Back to your original problem...

In the title of the question, you wrote

> deallocating already deallocated does not give a compiler error

If you read my statement before, it's hopefully logical that this will not be a compiler error but a runtime error instead.

I assume you meant a runtime error, because you also said:

> From my point of view , it should crash but program works flawless

And you did certainly not expect the compiler to crash.

I have copy/pasted your code into a Visual Studio 2017 C++ project. I ran x86 version in debug build and release build on Windows 7 SP1 x64 - and it crashed both times.

Debug build (run in debugger):

[image: Double free in debug build]

Release build (not run in debugger):

[image: Double free in release build]

In WinDbg, you can see that the destructor of the class calls `free()` and `free()` calls `HeapFree()` and `HeapFree()` detects the double free, and generates a `0xc0000374` exception.

```
0:000> *** Release Build, debugged when crashed
0:000> k
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 0036f9d0 775bf8a9 ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+0x57
01 0036f9e0 775bf989 ntdll!RtlpReportHeapFailure+0x21
02 0036fa14 7756d95c ntdll!RtlpLogHeapFailure+0xa1
03 0036fa44 0f64fddb ntdll!RtlFreeHeap+0x64
04 0036fa58 0f64fda8 ucrtbase!_free_base+0x1b
05 0036fa68 0137106d ucrtbase!free+0x18
06 (Inline) -------- DeallocateTwice!MyString::{dtor}+0x6 [c:\users\for example john\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\deallocatetwice\mystring.cpp @ 49] 
07 0036faa0 01371277 DeallocateTwice!main+0x6d [c:\users\for example john\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\deallocatetwice\deallocatetwice.cpp @ 11] 
08 (Inline) -------- DeallocateTwice!invoke_main+0x1c [f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl @ 78] 
09 0036fae8 74f0343d DeallocateTwice!__scrt_common_main_seh+0xfa [f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl @ 288] 
0a 0036faf4 77529802 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0b 0036fb34 775297d5 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
0c 0036fb4c 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

So IMHO, your assumption "it should crash" was a good assumption - I would have assumed it as well. And it didn't disappoint me.

---

How to proceed...

Next time, be precise in your language, so that people start trusting you. If you mix compile time and runtime, or mix stack and heap, or flip physical RAM and virtual memory, that's not a good starting point.

To get help for such cases, you need to ask better questions. Don't ask what the C++ standard says. In most cases it will be "undefined".

Instead, post the exact environment, potentially even more exact than I did. Give us the compiler version numbers and compiler command line options. Create a minimal, complete, viable example for us to reproduce. Show your debugging skills and how far you came.

Then, someone might come and give you an answer why it didn't crash in your case, like:

- you have ignored the exception in the debugger (like `sxi` in WinDbg).
- you have activated automatic crash dump collection. The program actually crashed, but you didn't notice it.
- you have disabled Windows Error Reporting.
- you attached the debugger to the wrong process.
- ...